# Why am I getting "you cannot call a method on a null valued expression"?

Tags: xml, powershell, xaml, checkbox, event-handling

I have an xaml with this structure

```
<Grid>
   <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmlData},XPath=//@Name}">
      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="Check1">
               <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding XPath.}"/>
            </CheckBox>
         </DataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
   </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

that I am attempting to add a handler to with the code

```
    [System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$check_checked={param($sender,$e) {write-host "testing"}
     $var_Check1.addhandler([System.Windows.Controls.Checkbox]::CheckedEvent,$check_checked)
```

This code processes xml

```
    $xamlfile="D:\foods.xml"
    $inputXAML=get-content -path $xamlfile
    $inputXAML = $inputXAML -replace "x:N" , "N" -replace '^<Win.*','<Window'
    [XML]$XAML=$inputXAML
    $reader=new-object system.xml.xmlnodereader $XAML
```

This code initializes the variables

```
    try{ 
       $psform = [windows.markup.xamlreader]::load($reader)
    }catch{
       write-host $_.exception
       throw
    }
```

The idea and thought behind this entire program is to have the treeview with checkboxes so I can perform an action on only the selected items. The code for the xml is

```
    <Foods>
        <UnhealthyFoods Name ="Candy"/>
            <Food Foodname = "MMs" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Skittles" >
            </Food>
            <Food Foodname = "Starburst" >
            </Food>
        </UnhealthyFoods>
        <HealthyFoods>
            <FoodGroup1 Name ="Vegetables"/>
            <Food Foodname = "Spinach" >
                </Food>
                <Food Foodname = "Brocolli" >
                </Food>
                <Food Foodname = "Greens" >
                </Food>
        </FoodGroup1>
        </HealthyFoods>
        <HealthyFoods>
            <FoodGroup2 Name ="Fruits"/>
            <Food Foodname = "Apples" >
                </Food>
                <Food Foodname = "Pears" >
                </Food>
                <Food Foodname = "Cherries" >
                </Food>
        </FoodGroup2>
        </HealthyFoods>
    </Foods>
```

So the three checkboxes should show up as (pretend these are checkboxes)

- Candy
- Vegetables
- Fruit

Ideally I click a button that performs an action on the selected groups, alas I can't make it that far

Exact Error message

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression
At F:\gui1.ps1:123 char:1
Category info Invalid Operation (:)
Fully qualifiederrorid : Invokemethod on null
```

that line is

```
 $var_Check1.addhandler([System.Windows.Controls.Checkbox]::CheckedEvent,$check_checked)
```

Comment: This implies that `$var_Check1` contains `$null`, not the object you expect.